# Angular v4. Bound variable to property that DOM element that isn't yet exists

Tags: angular

The pattern would like to get the currentTime of video element.

I did try to:

```
export class Cool implements OnInit {
  showVideo=true;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  video = document.getElementById('video')
  progress = 0;


  AfterViewInit () {
    this.progress = parseInt(this.video.currentTime);  
  }
}\
```

But get an error that a property doesn't yet exists

Comment: move the ` video = document.getElementById('video')` inside the `ngOnInit` and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is you have not overridden  `ngAfterViewInit` properly. And then you are trying to access DOM element before it is loaded. Move `video = document.getElementById('video')` inside `ngAfterViewInit`

```
export class Cool implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
      showVideo=true;
      private video ;
      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {}

      progress = 0;

      ngAfterViewInit () {
          this.video = document.getElementById('video')
          this.progress = parseInt(this.video.currentTime);  
      }
}
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively instead of making use of Id parameter, make use of template references

```
 @ViewChild('video') private video: ElementRef;   //reference to video element
```

Assuming you have following video tag

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay #video>
  <source src="somsrc" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

and then     `this.video.nativeElement;`
 gives you the whole video element object

Comment: Should be using @ViewChild('video')  Video: ElementRef....   if you want to  get access to element angular-way and bind it.

Comment: @Dipak You are very much correct in angular's perspective, but there is no harm doing `document.getElementById('video')`. It will still return you the html element.

Comment: yes but OP has angular focus, so answer need to encourage proper practice.. i guess rather then hack on top of hack.  :)

Comment: in fact he should be hooking to progressChange or similar event, and should not need direct access to DOM video element, does not need AfterViewInit etc... that's too much to educate someone.. appreciate your effort. :)